# "this" keyword in sequelize does not refer to the current instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I create a User model like this and I want to write a function to update user's password updatePassword():

```
"use strict";
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    instanceMethods:{
      updatePassword: function(newPass, callback){
        console.log("current pass in update: " + this.password);
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt){
          bcrypt.hash(newPass, salt, function(err, hashed){
            console.log("current pass: " + this.password);
            this.password = hashed;
            return callback();
          });
        });
      },
      comparePassword: function(password, callback){
        bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(err, isMatch){
          if(err) {
            throw err;
          }
          callback(isMatch);
        });
      }
    }
```

the first log `console.log("current pass in update: " + this.password);` prints password of the current object but the second `console.log("current pass: " + this.password);` does not work and it prints an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined`. Why it happened and how to solve ?

Comment: Please search before you post a question, because this is answered so many times before.

Comment: Sorry, I think in Sequelize is difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using `function` to define the callbacks for `bycrypt`

Solution 1 (plain ES5) is to define a self to refer to (the wanted) `this` prior to registering the call:

```
...
console.log("current pass in update: " + this.password);
var self = this;
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt){
  bcrypt.hash(newPass, salt, function(err, hashed){
    console.log("current pass: " + self.password);
    self.password = hashed;
    ...
```

Solution 2 (ES6 which Node supports for quite a while now) is to use an arrow function which automatically takes care of this for you:

```
...
console.log("current pass in update: " + this.password);
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt) => {
  bcrypt.hash(newPass, salt, (err, hashed) => {
    console.log("current pass: " + this.password);
    this.password = hashed; // note this in an arrow function refers to the 'uppper' this
    ...
```